# How can X-rays be emitted from a black hole?

Tags: black-hole, gravity, hawking-radiation, x-ray

A black hole's gravity prevents light from escaping, how can a black hole emit X-rays? Visible light and X-rays are both electromagnetic radiation, shouldn't the black hole's gravity prevent X-rays from escaping?

What about [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation)  that is predicted to be released by [black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole).

Comment: @JamesK No my question is different.

Comment: Please edit to clarify how it is different.  That question asks "How can a supermassive black hole be able to pull matter, but not the light photons of the energy?"

Comment: @Astrodude Both X-rays and Hawking radiation are phenomena that occur outside of the event horizon, so they can of course move away from the black hole.